# How to break a for loop when an integer is entered?

Tags: c++, iphone, for-loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int i;
int e;
int p;

char name[10] = {};
cout<<endl<<"Please enter the letters of your name separated by enter, when you are done, type 'quit' "<<endl;

for (e=0; e <= 10; e++)
{
    cin>>name[e];
    if (name[e] == 'quit')
    {
      break;

    }
}
for (p=0; p < ; p++)
{
    cout<<name[p];
}
return 0;
}
```

I want the user to input their name not bigger than 10 characters, but if the user enters quit, I want to end the loop. Please help with my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int i;
int e;
int p;

vector<string> name;
cout<<endl<<"Please enter the letters of your name separated by enter, when you are done, type 'quit' "<<endl;

while(1)
{
    string tmp;
    cin>>tmp;
    if (tmp == "quit")
    {
      break;

    }
    else if(tmp.size()>10)
    {
       cout<<"Enter name with less then 11 character"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
       name.push_back(tmp);
    }
}
for (auto n : name)
{
    cout<<n<<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) for it. Also it would be easier for you to use std::string to collect data and check size of input

Answer (score 0):

"quit" is a string, it contains 4 characters. you cannot treat it as a single character. so you must use double quotes "" instead of single quotes''.
also, this string is saved in an array of characters, not a single char variable. so

```
if (name[e] == 'quit')
```

is totally wrong.